# Android - Control image to move within the screen only?

Tags: java, android, scale

I am scaling, rotating and moving a image. I would like the image to stay within the screen view when moving the image. Everything else works fine.

This question has been asked before, but there is no answer. Any help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
private ImageView img_scale;
private float mScaleFactor = 0.5f;
private float mRotationDegree = 0.f;
private float mFocusX = 0.f;
private float mFocusY = 0.f;
private int mScreenHeight;
private int mScreenWidth;
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector;
private MoveGestureDetector mMoveDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img_scale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_scale);
    img_scale.setOnTouchListener(this);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    mScreenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    mScreenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    Bitmap loadTempImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exercise_icon);
    mImageHeight = loadTempImg.getHeight();
    mImageWidth = loadTempImg.getWidth();
    img_scale.setImageBitmap(loadTempImg);
    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    img_scale.setImageMatrix(matrix);


    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new ScaleListener());
    mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(getApplication(), new RotateListener());
    mMoveDetector = new MoveGestureDetector(getApplication(), new MoveListener());

}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.0f));
        return true;
    }
}

private class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
        mRotationDegree -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
        return true;
    }
}

private class MoveListener extends MoveGestureDetector.SimpleOnMoveGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
        PointF d = detector.getFocusDelta();
        mFocusX += d.x;
        mFocusY += d.y;




        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    float scaleImageCenterX = (mImageWidth * mScaleFactor) / 2;
    float scaleImageCenterY = (mImageHeight * mScaleFactor) / 2;

    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    matrix.postRotate(mRotationDegree, scaleImageCenterX, scaleImageCenterY);
    matrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaleImageCenterX, mFocusY - scaleImageCenterY);

    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: See this example [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

Comment: @sohailehmad I just went through that whole page, it took me very long to do so, but I could not find anything that helped me, if you say my answer is there, can you please answer my question with a code snippet. thank you

Comment: You can use above ImageView in your code to translate and scale. But you will need to implement rotation in it. Then in methods `fixTrans()` and `fixScaleTrans()` you can make sure that image stays in view.